# HTML Button not working for calling PHP file

Tags: php, html

I have created a php file which has the following piece of code. The form calls the process-simple-search.php file to process the keyword entered by the user. I am using MAMP and the files are stored as expected in the MAMP folder. The click of the button however doesn't do anything, I have tried everything but no results...do you have any suggestion?

```
 <form method="GET" action="process-simple-search.php">
  <fieldset id="general-search">
   <label>Please insert the desired keyword:</label>
   <div id="components">    
    <select name="items">
     <option value="dogs">Dogs</option>
     <option value="cats">Cats</option>
     <option value="rhinos">Rhinos</option>
    </select>
    <input id="textfield" type="text" name="text" value="" size="42"></input>
    <input id="button" type="button" name="button" value="Search"></input>
   </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Does the Search Button have any JS Events attached to it?  You can consider changing its type to 'submit' and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your button type to submit

```
 <form method="GET" action="process-simple-search.php">
  <fieldset id="general-search">
   <label>Please insert the desired keyword:</label>
   <div id="components">    
    <select name="items">
     <option value="dogs">Dogs</option>
     <option value="cats">Cats</option>
     <option value="rhinos">Rhinos</option>
    </select>
    <input id="textfield" type="text" name="text" value="" size="42"></input>
    <input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="Search"></input>
   </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the HTML input button.
You should be using the submit button one instead, so that it will submit the form.

Try this

```
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="Search"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the type of the button to "submit":

```
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="Search"/>
```